# TextInput's content is not center vertical

Tags: react-native

I found the `TextInput`'s content is not centered vertical (in some android devices like HUAWEI), when the `TextInput`'s parent style is `{flexDirection: 'row'}`,
It looks like the baseline is center, and text is more upper.

[image]

Comment: And what if you also add  `alignItems: 'center'` to its style?

Comment: There's an Android specific style property called `textAlignVertical`. Use that with value `center` and you should be all good.

Comment: @Cherniv  I tried alignItems: 'center',it show center horizontal

Comment: @zvona textAlignVertical does not work for single line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally found the reason,this is because TextInput has default padding, My solution is add paddingTop: 0,paddingBottom: 0,to the TextInput style.

Comment: then my text is stick to top of textinput